# adding values to a row in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using ajax function to call a method on server side which will return a set of values, I need to add these values to the next row of a jqgrid. How to insert values to a jqid by iterating the rownumber?

Answer (score 1):

After you receive the data from the the server you can add there to the grid. For example, if your grid has `colModel` with column names `'invid'`,`'invdate'`,`'amount'`,`'tax'`,`'total'`,`'note'`. The code which add the row could be about following

```
var myfirstrow = {invid:"1", invdate:"2007-10-01", note:"note",
                  amount:"200.00", tax:"10.00", total:"210.00"};
$("#grid_id").jqGrid("addRowData","1", myfirstrow);
```

where `"1"` is the `id` of the data which you want to add.

If you want to add data to a special position in the grid, for example, after the selected row you can do almost the same:

```
var grid = $("#grid_id");
var selRowId=grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
var myData = {invid:"1", invdate:"2007-10-01", note:"note",
                  amount:"200.00", tax:"10.00", total:"210.00"};
grid.jqGrid("addRowData", "1", myData, "after", selRowId);
```

See [Data Manipulation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) part of the jqGrid documentation. By the way with respect of [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#methods) method you can add many rows to a grid at one call. In the case the data parameter must be array of row data.